# How to connect objects with Bezier-like curves using Paper.js

Tags: javascript, canvas, paperjs

I have a web app prototype where nodes similar to Blender shader editor are connected to each other. I am using Paper.js framework

I want them to be connected using those smooth Bezier-like curves. So I have 2 shapes and I can connect them by making a straight line, but now I want to have handles at the endpoints that smooth these objects out, kinda like this:
[image]
So 2 handles on endpoints, pointing horizontally for half the bounding box of the path.
The problem is I can't figure out how to add and edit those handles using Paper.js
The code I have is this:

```
function makeRectangle(topLeft, size, cornerSize, colour){
    var rectangle = new Rectangle(topLeft, size);
    var cornerSize = cornerSize;
    var path = new Path.RoundRectangle(rectangle, cornerSize);
    path.fillColor = colour;
    return path;
}

var xy1 = new Point(50,50); //Position of 1st rectangle.
var size = new Size(100, 80); //Size
var c = new Size(8,8); //Corner radius
var col = "#167ee5"; //Colour

var r1 = makeRectangle(xy1, size, c, col); //Make first rectangle

var xy2 = new Point(467,310); //Position of second rectangle
var size2 = new Size(115, 70); //Size of second rectangle

var r2 = makeRectangle(xy2, size2, c, col); //Make secont rectangle

var r1cent = r1.bounds.center; //Get the center points, they will be used as endpoints for the curve.

var r2cent = r2.bounds.center;

var connector = new Path(r1cent, r2cent); //Ok so I made this path... Now what? How do access and edit the handlers at endpoints like in the image?

connector.strokeColor = 'black'; //Give it some colour so we can see it.
```

You can paste all this code [here](http://sketch.paperjs.org/) without any setup, it's a good way to test the framework.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Segment` objects when defining the connector rather than using `Point`s (or you can set the `handleIn` and `handleOut` properties after creating the path).

The doc is here: [`Segment`](http://paperjs.org/reference/segment/)

And here is a sketch showing how to use `handleIn` and `handleOut` with your code:

[sketch.paperjs.org solution](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#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)